# Login failed for user, connection string edit

Tags: asp.net, web-services, connection-string

I have an asp net service hosted on IIS.

[image]

After invoking one of the methods, to check the connection...

[image]

---

Db *OpRiskTZB* is attached to localhost, connections string set as following:
[image]

> Previously I connected successfully to non local server, now for
>   testing purposes I have to connect to localhost, what am I missing ?

---

**EDIT:**

As David suggested I checked Permissions,added the user to Users and Roles, but still no luck...

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Login failed means just that... the login failed.  Whichever database you're using doesn't permit a login for that user.

Comment: But why, I set the trusted connection as I am using windows authentication, connecting to localhost..
What went wrong ?

Comment: Have you checked the user permissions and security settings on the database?  (Both for the DB server and the DB itself.)  Just because the *client* says it can be trusted doesn't mean the *server* has any reason to trust it.

Comment: Can you see my edit?